# Emploi de la locution "O tempora, o mores"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, latin

Peut-on employer couramment la locution "O tempora, o mores" ? Parmi les deux traductions: "Quelle époque ! Quelles mœurs !" et "Ô temps ! Ô mœurs !" laquelle est plus reconnue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non, *O tempora, o mores* ne peut pas être employé couramment en français. Il n'y a plus guère de latinistes en France pour les comprendre.

Entre tes deux propositions, je choisirais :

> Quelle époque ! Quelles mœurs !

mais sinon, j'utiliserais cette expression plus courante, inspirée de la même origine :

> Autre temps, autre mœurs.

Answer (score 2):

> O tempora, O mores

est l'exemple type de la citation latine issue d'une culture classique qui s'est quelque peu perdue avec la baisse du nombre d'élèves latinistes. D'autre citations beaucoup plus courantes se sont bien maintenues (*a priori, pro rata, sine qua none*, *et caetera* etc.)

On trouve cette phrase dans Astérix, ce qui témoigne toute de même d'une certaine renommée, mais elle est aujourd'hui rarement utilisée à l'écrit et ne serait probablement pas comprise à l'oral (en dehors d'une émission littéraire par exemple).

Si le sens souhaité est bien de ["traduire l’indignation de celui qui l'utilise vis-à-vis des mœurs de son époque."](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/o_tempora,_o_mores)
Alors, dans une conversation informelle, on pourrait dire :

> Quelle époque!

On pourrait aussi entendre

> Tout se perd!

... éventuellement suivi de l'incontournable "de mon temps (...)"

Dans un contexte plus formel (sujet de journal télévisé, par exemple), j'ai le souvenir d'avoir déjà entendu la phrase proposée par jlliagre :

> Autre temps, autre mœurs.

...qui me semble un meilleur choix que *Ô temps, Ô mœurs*, que je n'ai jamais entendue utilisée. Mais du coup, on perd l'aspect indignation/critique du présent.

Comment: *A priori, pro rata, sine qua none, et caetera* ne sont pas vraiment des citations mais plutôt des expressions latines ayant subsisté telles qu'elles en français. Comme citations ayant tenu la distance, je dirais *veni vidi vinci* ou *alea jacat est*.

Answer (score 0):

**I** Première question

Oui, dans la conversation, on peut employer la forme latine, mais il est préférable de le faire avec des personnes dont on sait qu'elles sont des latinistes ou des personnes que l'on connait pour avoir beaucoup lu le français et qui de ce fait ne seront pas « dépaysées » par cette expression ; cette sorte d'interlocuteur a toujours été rare et elle l'est encore plus de nos jours ; donc, avec des personnes qui ont une éducation peu académique la forme latine n'est pas le meilleur des choix ; on peut cependant faire ce choix si l'on est prêt à ne pas être compris et que l'on pense être une bonne chose d'initier l'interlocuteur à un peu d'histoire sur la langue et sa culture, ce qu'il faudra faire, bien sûr, par l'intermédiaire d'une digression dans la conversation ; une digression n'est cependant pas souvent la bienvenue dans les conversations et n'est facile qu'avec des interlocuteurs à l'esprit ouvert et « agile ».
Dans la langue écrite, le choix est similaire, à cela près que des digressions sur des détails culturels doivent être introduites à bon escient et ne peuvent plus être façonnées selon la curiosité de l'interlocuteur puisqu'il ne participe plus.

**II** Seconde question
À mon avis la première traduction est préférable et sera le plus souvent utilisée, tout au moins dans la conversation. Cela semble être confirmé par  [wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_tempora,_o_mores), qui choisit la première comme premier choix, et le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/o_tempora,_o_mores), qui ignore totalement le second.

> (Wikipédia) « O tempora, o mores » est un incipit et une locution latine pouvant être traduite par « Quelle époque ! Quelles mœurs ! » ou bien par « Ô temps,  mœurs ».

> (Wiktionnaire)  o tempora, o mores
> (Proverbial) Quel temps, quelles mœurs.

L'utilisation de « ô » dans la langue parlée demande du locuteur des dons pour les effets théâtraux qui sont peu communs ; dans une conversation, il est plus facile  d'agencer le placement de la première et ainsi de donner une impression d'authenticité ; une mauvaise intonation sur les « ô » peut être perçue comme très gauche et ainsi ruiner l'effet que l'on recherche.